# How to use a ToolTip on a PlaceHolder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, placeholder

I have a placeholder control in ASP.NET 4.0 C#. I have displayed the data from my D drive 
(means mapped the files and folders from my drive to webpage using placeholder) to the webpage.

Now, when I hover over a placeholder row, I want to display some text using a **ToolTip** or any other control.

There are lots of examples for **GridView**, **ListBox**, etc., but I'm unable to find an example for **PlaceHolder**.

Comment: Do you mean [this placeholder control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: the placeholder in asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your placeholder with a panel and give the panel the tooltip.

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ToolTip="this is a placeholder tooltip example.">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            <span>Sample text</span>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: i ask did it work, though i know for sure that it does... how about an answer mark ;)

Answer (score 1):

placeholder isn't there in reality.  It's simply a placeholder that is used by ASP during the page life cycle.  So as the page loads, ASP places the specified controls into the place holder.  If you look at the HTML markup of the rendered page, there is no placeholder - just the controls you made.

To solve this, I have typically wrapped a placeholder inside of a panel.  Then set the tooltip on the panel.